# The recursive function call is 'out of reach' within my react component

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a react component and I want to apply a recursive function. I have a function call inside my recursive function that will call the main function once a process is done. The inner function call is not being called and it is saying that the function is out of reach. I am not sure how to ensure that I can call the main function from the inner function.

if you look in the code, under the HelpFolder call, I want to call the traverseFolder function again. that is what is showing `unreachable code detected`.

I tried using this.traverse folder which did not work.

```
const traverseFolder = (current:any) => {
        console.log(current.length)
        if(current.length > 0){
            for(var i = 0; i < current.length; i++){
                console.log(current[i].type)
                if(current[i].type === 'folder'){
                    console.log(current[i].name)
                    return(
                        <HelpFolder
                            type={current[i].type}
                            name={current[i].name}
                            path={current[i].path}
                        />
                    )
                    traverseFolder(current[i])
                } else {
                    return(
                        <HelpFile
                            type={current[i].type}
                            name={current[i].name}
                            path={current[i].path}
                        />
                    )
                }
            }
        } else {
            console.log('no folder')
            return(
                <div>
                    {} 
                </div>
            ) 
        }
    }
```

What I am expecting is that it displays 2 folders and 2 files but it is just showing the first folder.

Answer (score 1):

The code is unreachable because you put it after the `return`. Once you `return`, anything after that will not be executed and the function is exited. So put the function call before it.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `traverseFolder` function inside the return statement otherwise the code will not be executed

You should fix the code related to the folder part like this :

```
if(current[i].type === 'folder'){
  return(
    <>
      <HelpFolder
        type={current[i].type}
        name={current[i].name}
        path={current[i].path}
      />
      {traverseFolder(current[i])}
    </>
  );
}
```